# Help! Minecraft is being very weird!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

I tried to go on my servers but it says all the mods they have are out of date (spigot 1.8.3 i.e) or BungeeCord 1.8 and will not let my connect.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind! Go into launcher and then edit your profile. I was not only on snapshots, I was on latest version and so then I went back to 1.8.8. If anyone else has this problem, there you go.